# Running inline SQL with Entity Framework 5 and returning tracked Entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

How can I execute a command such as:

`SELECT * FROM CATS`

That behaves exactly as if I'd done `myContext.Cats.Where(c => true);` ?

Google suggested `context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()` but that returns an int. There is also context.Database.SqlQuery which looks promising, but it says that entities returned are not tracked, which I suspect is important (I'm not really familiar with how EF works in terms of tracking things).

It suggests using `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<TEntity>.SqlQuery(Object[])` to track it, but I'm not entirely sure what this means or how to implement it.

In addition to make it even more confusing I want to write a generic method to allow me to execute the specific query against any table.

Here's a rough example of what I'd like in pseudocode

```
public DbSet<T> ExecuteSelect<T>(DbContext context, string table)
{
     DbSet<T> entities = context.RunSql("SELECT * FROM " + table);

     return entities;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accoring to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx you want the following:

```
public IEnumerable<T> ExecuteSelect<T>(DbContext context, string table)
{
     IEnumerable<T> entities = context.Set<T>.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM " + table).ToList();

     return entities;
}
```

`myContext.Cats.Where(c => true)` returns `IQueriable<Cat>` (not DbSet)

**BUT**

Your returned set will actually be finalized already (eg you cant add extra bits to your query later) so having it Queriable is misdirecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute sql queries directly as follows :

```
        private int DeleteData()
    {
        using (var ctx = new MyEntities(this.ConnectionString))
        {
            if (ctx != null)
            {

                //Delete command
                return ctx.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM ALARM WHERE AlarmID > 100");

            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

For select we may use

```
using (var context = new MyContext()) 
{ 
    var blogs = context.MyTable.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable").ToList(); 
}
```